# Hashed Passwords and Identity attacks - best practise

Tags: sql-server

I have a database I am converting from storing plain text passwords to replacing them with password hashes. Is it recommended to take the extra step of using SQL Server column encryption to prevent the hashes being extracted by an attacker ?

The form of attack I am trying to prevent is where an attacker uses a well known password list combined with an copy of my database user table, and just does a dictionary attack by hashing the well known password list and comparing the outcome with the stored hash. They would probably get a certain percentage of success, and with normal levels of password re-use amongst users, they would be able to use the user email address/login with the cracked password to attempt an identity theft.

Initially I had considered hashing of passwords to be adequate, but wonder if its best practise then to encrypt the hash column to prevent a physical copy of the table (got through whatever devious means) being able to be used for this kind of attack.

My question is whether this is "best or common practise" amongst DBAs. This could apply to any hash storage of known data fields, but in this circumstance its held within a SQL Server database.

Comment: The "certain percentage of success" is probably well over 90%. The password lists run to 10 million entries ordered by occurrence. Salting only eliminates rainbow tables and discovering one password hash does not disclose all other users with the same password. DBAs are not the group to ask about security, you need to ask security domain experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration (the salt needs to be saved with the hash). Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).
See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

Just hashing, even using an HMAC with a random salt is not enough. On my laptop I can run a 20 byte password through SHA-512 and compare in under 1us so with just a SHA-512 hash I can try 1,000,000 passwords a second.

For more information see:
Password list at [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).
Infosec [password-cracking-tools](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/10-popular-password-cracking-tools/)
Arstechnica [How I became a password cracker](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/03/how-i-became-a-password-cracker/3/).

Comment: Good cross references, and sources for password lists.